# Extracting and parsing data from JSON file with multiple nests

Tags: html, json, parsing, nested

I'm attempting to build a simple election results page to pull data from a JSON file. However, that file has multiple races, and I don't want to display them in. Instead I want to cherry pick races and then display their results.

I would prefer to do this through HTML but can also do this on PHP if necessary.

The JSON file is being created via a script that is scraping a state website for an XML file, and then converting it into a JSON file that is then uploaded to a server on a schedule.

Below is a snippet showing one race of many from the file. What I'm wanting to do, is be able to select certain races, in this instance "State Rep. Dist. 080", display the precincts reporting (which is the r_prec and t_prec fields) and then list the candidates and their respective information.

I have the skills to make it pretty, but am unfamiliar with JSON in general so having difficulty getting started with how to parse the data. For testing, I have tried to pull just this data into a validated JSON code and parse, but have had no luck with that. Eventually, though, I will need to be able to cherry pick races as the JSON file will have all elections being run in the state, not just the ones I'm wanting.

Appreciate any and all help! I've searched around the internet for some time but just haven't been able to have a breakthrough on this. I can't seem to find anything for what seems to be a more advanced application. Thanks!

```
"State Rep. Dist. 080": {
    "r_prec": 0,
    "t_prec": 32,
    "candidates": [{
        "n": "Larry Sheets",
        "v": 0,
        "p": "R",
        "per": 0
    }, {
        "n": "Levi Grenko",
        "v": 0,
        "p": "D",
        "per": 0
    }, {
        "n": "Garrett W. Byrd",
        "v": 0,
        "p": "L",
        "per": 0
    }, {
        "n": "Write-in",
        "v": 0,
        "p": "",
        "per": 0
    }]
},
```

Comment: You can't use HTML alone to parse JSON data.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in an HTML page, using JS. I have a couple server options, basically, and the one I'd prefer to store this script on doesn't have PHP installed.

Comment: Alright, so you want to parse this JSON data and render it in HTML?

Comment: Yes. I fiddled some more and got down parsing simple data with jQuery, but still couldn't figure out how to parse something more complex like I'm dealing with.

Comment: Can you put your code on jsfiddle?

Comment: Here's a link to the code I figured out to at least get the data to show-up in my console. But the looping/displaying I've not gotten any further with: https://jsfiddle.net/bm5qe0xh/

Here is a link to another code I was working on last night based on further tutorials out there, but couldn't get all the errors cleared. https://jsfiddle.net/uh906bmq/

Comment: Ok, maybe I'm getting close. Here's another stab: https://jsfiddle.net/stjs623c/

This is returning Name: undefined.

If I console.log(race) it shows the values it should: r_prec and t_prec and candidates. The JSON file can be seen here: http://static.cnhionline.com/dailyiowegian/results/election-2016-results-simplified.json

Comment: I've come up with the below. It appears to be working, but it's not very efficient. How can I do one query and have it cycle through and list every candidate instead of selecting them by [0], [1], etc. Does that make sense what I'm asking?

https://jsfiddle.net/x3sp6uzd/1/

Comment: Your jsfiddle doesn't seem to work. Anyway, the algorithm for this in simple in theory. You just traverse the JSON tree, finding parent and child elements, and map them with `ul` and `li` elements respectively. That'll give you what you want.